# watchOS1 - When notification arrives, first InterfaceController loads too

Tags: watchkit

Every time the Watch receives a notification (let's say local), either the static long look or the dynamic long look interface is loaded.

However, what I am observing is that every time the corresponding watch app's first interface controller is also getting loaded.

Is it something that other people have also observed?

1. Every time the Watch receives a notification, the watch app's first interface controller also gets run behind the scenes.
2. If it really does, how to distinguish when the watch app ran because user opened it and when it ran because there was a notification that came? context in awakeWithContext: is null in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I noticed too. It also seems it is in charge to handle the action methods for for local and remote Notification when tap on a button:

   handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:
2. I think you can use:

   didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletion:

or

```
didReceiveLocalNotification::withCompletion:
```

to detect when your app is populated from a remote or local notification

Comment: Nope. All the actions are background actions. They are still handled by the appDelegate. So that part is fine. Its just that I don't know why the interface controller had to fire here.

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the WatchKit 2.0 where the Watch App extension is in the Watch not in the iOS device

Answer (score 0):

As of watchOS 3 you can out exit of `awake(withContext:)` early in this scenario by inspecting the `applicationState` of your extension:

```swift
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    if #available(watchOS 3.0, *) {
        if WKExtension.shared().applicationState == .background {
            print("Awake with Context in background.  Not processing.")
            return
        }
    }

    // otherwise, load normally
}
```